# Existence of stable spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology, dimension-theory, products

An element $X$ of a class of topological spaces is called the **stable space** for that class if for every space $Y$ in the class we have that $X\times Y$ is homeomorphic to $X$. Note that a stable space for a given class, if it exists, is topologically unique. Important examples of stable spaces are:

> - the Cantor set $2^\omega$ for the zero-dimensional compacta
> - the space of irrational numbers $\mathbb P$ for the zero-dimensional complete ($G_\delta$)-spaces
> - $\mathbb Q ^\omega$ for the zero-dimensional $F_{\sigma\delta}$-spaces.

There are many other zero-dimensional examples, but this question is about (separable metric) **almost zero-dimensional** (AZD) spaces. A space is AZD if it has a basis of open sets whose closures are intersections of clopen sets. Equivalently,  $X$ is AZD if $X$ is homeomorphic to the graph of an upper semi-continuous function $\varphi:Z\to[0,1]$ with zero-dimensional domain $Z$. Almost zero-dimensionality is hereditary and is preserved by countable products (similar to zero-dimensionality).

The class of AZD Polish spaces has a stable element which is analogous to the space $\mathbb P$ in the class of zero-dimensional Polish spaces. That stable element is $\mathfrak E_c^\omega$, the $\omega$-power of complete Erdős space
$$\mathfrak E_c:=\{x\in \ell^2:x_n\in \mathbb P \text{ for all }n<\omega\}.$$ This was proved by Jan Dijkstra in 2011 in the reference below. In their 2010 paper, Dijkstra and Jan van Mill asked whether the  plain (rational) Erdős space $$\mathfrak E:=\{x\in \ell^2:x_n\in \mathbb Q \text{ for all }n<\omega\}$$ is stable in the class of AZD $F_{\sigma\delta}$-spaces. But I just proved that it is not: [ArXiv link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.05874.pdf).

As far as I know $\mathfrak E$ was the only reasonable candidate for a stable AZD $F_{\sigma\delta}$-space. My question is: **Is there any (theoretical) reason to believe that a stable AZD $F_{\sigma\delta}$-space actually exists?**

Note that it cannot be $\mathfrak E ^\omega$ because that space is homeomorphic to $\mathfrak E$.  On the other hand, I believe there is a  conjecture that the homeomorphism group of $\mathfrak E_{\mathrm{c}}$ is  homeomorphic to $\mathfrak E_{\mathrm{c}}^\omega$, so perhaps the homeomorphism group of $\mathfrak E$ is stable in its class.

*Dijkstra, Jan J.*, [**Characterizing stable complete Erdős space**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s11856-011-0149-7), Isr. J. Math. 186, 477-507 (2011). [ZBL1257.54036](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1257.54036).

Comment: "Compacta" = compact Hausdorff metrizable spaces?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე yes I assume all spaces here are separable metrizable.  so compacta = compact metrizable